# Is there any way to simplify nested, namespaced resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, refactoring, routes

Is there any less redundant way to do this?

```
resources :tournaments do
    resources :commitments,     controller: "tournaments/commitments"
    resources :constraints,     controller: "tournaments/constraints"
    resources :entries,         controller: "tournaments/entries"
    resources :buildings,       controller: "tournaments/buildings" do
        resources :rooms,       controller: "tournaments/buildings/rooms"
    end
end
```

Comment: You have asked 11 questions and accepted none of them. Please accept the correct answers on those questions -- people will be more willing to help. .. If you do, reply to me here and I'll help you organize your controllers.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that was an option... I'm going back and doing that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the convention for nested resources. Here all of the controllers are still in the app/controllers directory.

```
resources :tournaments do
    resources :commitments
    resources :constraints
    resources :entries
    resources :buildings do
        resources :rooms
    end
end
```

You generally only use directories for your controllers when you need namespacing, like:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
  root :to=>"dashboards#admin"
end

#/admin/users
```

Comment: Yes I need namespacing. Entries, for example, is used under a different resource. Even for resources that don't necessarily need to be namespaced, I’d like them to be in separate parts of the application.